# Wie würdet ihr „das Hamburger Sie“ ins Englische übersetzen?

Tags: german-to-english

Wenn sowas in einem auf Deutsch geschrieben Buch erschiene, und ihr den Begriff ins Englische übersetzen müsstet, was würdet ihr tun? Eine leichte Übersetzung geht nicht. Und wie wäre es gegebenenfalls mit dem Münchner Du?

**Kontext der Frage** (aus einem Kommentar des OP):

Kommt ein neuer Chef in die Firma und wir müssen uns siezen. Aber er fragt mich, „wie wäre es mit dem Hamburger Sie?“ Ich sage „Ok. Wie soll ich Sie anreden?“ Er sagt, „Hans, Chef. Es ist mir egal.“ Er fragt, „Und Sie? Wie soll ich Sie anreden?“ Ich erwidere, „Jan bitte.“ Wenn sowas in einem Roman stünde, wie würde man das kurze Gespräch ins Englische übersetzen?

Comment: Ich würde sowas wie "The Hamburg politeness form" schreiben.

Comment: Das Hamburger Sie was ist damit gemeint? Also vom Kontext her

Comment: Ohne, dass du beschreibst, welche Signifikanz der Begriff im und für das Buch hat, kann man dir nicht raten - Handelt es sich um eine Dokumentation über Anreden oder ist es ein Roman, bei dem jemand mit dem "Sie" angesprochen wird? Wenn es ein Roman ist, ist die Anrede für die Handlung relevant?

Comment: @seb Verwendung von <Vorname> + "Sie" als Anrede. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_Sie

Comment: Ok, da würde ich Rudy Recht geben

Comment: Was ist "das Hamburger Sie"? Etwas mehr Kontext würde dieser Frage gut tun.

Comment: Möchtest Du den Begriff *Hamburger »Sie«* ins Englische übersetzen, oder möchtest Du Dialoge, die das Hamburger Sie verwenden, ins Englische übersetzen?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Die Anführungsstriche lassen da wenig Interpretationsraum.

Comment: Dazu fällt mir ein: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlX-bTJ7XUM - Graf Yoster, hanseatisch steif, sagt "Johann, fahren Sie nach Hause" (Hamburger Sie), steigt in seinen Rolls Royce mit **Münchner** Kennzeichen und fährt ab.

Answer (score 7):

Das "Hamburger Sie" in einem englischen Roman zu erklären, dürfte in etwa so schwierig sein, wie einem Blinden die Farben erklären zu wollen. 
Es ist alleine schon schwierig, das Konzept des Siezens und Duzens  in eine Sprache zu transferieren, in der das nicht vorhanden ist ("politeness form" oder "semi-formal addressing" trifft es eigentlich nicht richtig) - Das "Hamburger Sie" oder "Münchner Du" sind Nuancen davon, die noch schwieriger zu verstehen sind.

Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, dass das *Hamburger Sie* für eine Handlung so relevant sein kann, dass man in einem Roman auch nur einen einzelnen Absatz zur Erklärung spendieren würde - Das dürfte sich stilistisch so anfühlen, wie wenn man versuchen würde, eine Hintergrundmusik, die nichts zur Handlung beiträgt, mit Worten zu beschreiben. Am einfachsten dürfte noch sein, zu beschreiben, *welche Gefühle* (z.B. "I was proud to be allowed to address him by first name" o.Ä, auch wenn das das "Hamburger Sie" nicht exakt trifft) in den Akteuren durch die Anreden hervorgerufen würden.

Im Übrigen kann ich mir auch kaum einen deutschen Roman vorstellen, in dem die Anredeform so relevant wäre, dass sie als Begrifflichkeit erwähnt würde. Wie die Kommentare zeigen, können selbst sehr viele Muttersprachler auf Anhieb nicht sagen, was das "Hamburger Sie" bedeutet.

Answer (score 6):

Wie tofro schon schrieb ist es fast unmöglich das Konzept des *Hamburger Sie* eins zu eins zu übersetzen. Aber Dank der Erweiterung der Frage um etwas Kontext und etwas dichterischer Freiheit kann man das umgehen.

> Kommt ein neuer Chef in die Firma und wir müssen uns siezen. Aber er fragt mich, „wie wäre es mit dem Hamburger Sie?“ Ich sage „Ok. Wie soll ich Sie anreden?“ Er sagt, „Hans, Chef. Es ist mir egal.“ Er fragt, „Und Sie? Wie soll ich Sie anreden?“ Ich erwidere, „Jan bitte.“ Wenn sowas in einem Roman stünde, wie würde man das kurze Gespräch ins Englische übersetzen?

Wenn es darum geht einen Text zu übersetzen muss man fast immer Kompromisse eingehen. Wortspiele sind etwa nur schwer oder gar nicht zu übersetzen. Anagramme müssen komplett umgeschrieben werden, damit sie funktionieren. Man denke nur an Tom Vorlost Riddle (im Original Tom Marvolo Riddle) aus der Harry Potter Reihe.

Zum Teil werden kulturelle Konzepte angepasst oder umgeschrieben, weil sie vom anderssprachigen Zielpublikum so nicht verstanden werden. Um so einen Fall handelt es sich hier.

**Wie könnte man den Abschnitt nun anpassen?**

Wenn man es nicht so eng sieht kann man sagen, dass in vielen (amerikanischen) Firmen eine Sprachkultur eingeführt wurde die eine Art Hamburger Sie nutzt, da sich die Mitarbeiter dort stets mit dem Vornamen ansprechen. Traditionelle Höflichkeitsformen wie Sir oder Ma'am sind zwar auf dem Rückzug, aber immer noch verbreitet.

Entsprechend könnte man den Absatz etwa wie folgt umschreiben: Grammatikfehler bitte ignorieren ;)

> He: "Please, don't be formal" Me: "Ok. How should I address you, sir?" He:"Hans ... Boss ... I don't care but please drop the sir. And you? How should I address you?" Me:"Call me Jan."

Comment: Tolle Übersetzung. Vielen Dank.

Answer (score 3):

Da es das Siezen im Englischen nicht gibt, lässt man es besser auf Deutsch: "The Hamburger 'Sie'" oder so in der Art. Der Buchinhalt oder die Kurzzusammenfassung muss das dann erklären.

Auch in den Gesprächen verwendet man den Begriff unübersetzt. Es ist eine deutsche Besonderheit, die sich für den Leser aus dem Kontext erschließt.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn etwas nicht wirklich übersetzt werden kann, weil in der Ausgangssprache ein Konzept oder ein Sprachkonstrukt existiert, für das es in der Zielsprache keine Entsprechung gibt, wird im Deutschen üblicherweise eine Erklärung in eine Fußnote gepackt (seltener in einen Einschub) und diese mit dem Kürzel *Anm. d. Übers.* (kurz für *Anmerkung des Übersetzers*) eingeleitet. Häufig tritt so etwas auch bei Wortspielen auf oder wenn es um ein für die Handlung relevantes Missverständnis aufgrund phonetischer Ähnlichkeit geht.
Ich würde Dir raten, in der englischen Stack Exchange zu fragen, welches die im Englischen übliche Form for derartige Erklärungen ist.